# how can I achieve dynamic namespace imports in pylons / mako?

Tags: python, pylons, mako

I am using pylons with mako as templating engine and I have a template which uses

```
<%namespace name="foo" file="../bar.html"/>
```

and

```
${foo.someFunction()}
```

to call someFunction(). This way it is working correctly, but now I need the file *"../bar.html"* to be changeable dynamically like:

```
<%namespace name="foo" file="${c.filename}"/>
```

where *c.filename* is set in the controller. This way it isn't working and I get the following exception:

***NameError: global name 'c' is not defined***

Everywhere else in the template *${c.filename}* is working correctly.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this import dynamically?

Thanks in advance,
ashiaka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working when I use:

```
<%namespace name="foo" file="${context['tmpl_context'].filename}"/>
```

respectively

```
<%namespace name="foo" file="${context['c'].filename}"/>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. What version of Mako are you using?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know this anymore. The only thing I can remember is that I worked with pylons version 0.9.7 and its mako version...